# Desarrollo web y apps: tener multiples carousels en una página

Tags: javascript, app

estoy intentando tener varios carousels en una misma página. Parto de este codepen de ejemplo que solo tiene uno:

See the Pen [multiple items per slide in bootstrap carousel](https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY/) by Maurice Melchers ([@mephysto](https://codepen.io/mephysto)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Y he probado a duplicar el código html para un segundo carousel añadiendo al nombre de las clases el número 2 (por eso de que es el segundo carousel), también duplico el código del CSS y le añado el 2 a algunas referencias para que coincidan con los nombres de las clases que he cambiado. También he modificado el java script, volviendo a duplicar el código y añadiendo el número 2 a la expresión: `$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function()` quedando: `$('.multi-item-carousel .item2').each(function()`
El problema es que me aparece un segundo carousel (el que tiene imágenes de cazas) pero al pulsar los extremos me cambia solo las imágenes del primero en vez del carousel para el que estoy pulsando los botones. Además me aparece como un mosaico de imágenes para el segundo carousel. Podeís ver en este codepen (que es fork del anterior):

See the Pen [My first carousel](https://codepen.io/Baldan/pen/YvEoBm/) by Guillermo ([@Baldan](https://codepen.io/Baldan)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Por si no se entiende, mi pregunta es cómo hacer para tener dos carousels en una misma página, si me podeís dar alguna pista como por ejemplo los parámetros a modificar  del html, css y javascript os lo agradecería o alguna forma de analizar el problema. Eso si, si me vaís a dar alguna pista hacerlo a través de una respuesta y no de un comentario, más que nada para que pueda validar la respuesta y concluir la pregunta por amor a este sitio y a su comunidad para que no se llene de preguntas sin respuesta.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si observas bien en el código que tienes en codepen:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- add  more items here -->
          <!-- Example item start:  -->
          
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          
          <!--  Example item end -->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

En la linea 5 tiene una propiedad id="theCarousel" luego hasta la parte de abajo se declaran los controles para desplazar a la izquierda o derecha:

```html
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Solo necesitas modificar el id del carousel y el id de referencia de los controles para que quede algo así:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel2">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <!-- add  more items here -->
          <!-- Example item start:  -->
          
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          
          <!--  Example item end -->
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel2" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel2" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos!

PD. El css está escrito en Less, por lo que ese código si lo pones en un css normal no te va a servir.